# Lookup and calculate value of children for a parent list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm calculating the total hours of my member spending for working in each task by count the hours they spend for each subtask of that task.

I have a list of tasks (include parent tasks and subtasks). Each task in that list has Parent Key column (available if it is a subtask),Key colum, Task Name, Task Type, Assigned Persron and Time (hourse spent for that task of that person).

- Each Task could have multiple subtask which could be assigned to multiple Person
- Each Person could have multiple subtasks of one Parent Task.

Now I need to create a list of Task (without subtask) and then list subtasks of each person and calculate total hours each member spent for that task:

- If that Task doesn't have subtask, the time will be the spent time of that task.
- If that Task has subtask, the time will be the total time spent for subtask (It means don't calculate time spent for the parent task)
- If a member they have 2 or more subtasks in a single Task, the total hours will be sum of their subtasks.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mSLDyRFyG71HxCFwds7M3uoCH3cgNogoREJZZbA3lD0/edit#gid=0

I could get a list of Parent task but I cannot sum the multiple subtasks of each Person.

Comment: I just checked out the shared sheet and yet to get a clear picture on which `subtasks` are linked to which `tasks`? Is it just the order of how they were listed OR do we need to sort the `Task key` number? Coming to your desired output table I dont seem to understand how Person A has 7 hours for `Task G` or Person B` has 7 hrs for `Task X` and so on.... hoping you could provide a noob explanation in your sample sheet regarding the numbers in your expected ouput table so that we can try a solution. cool

Comment: Hi. No need to sort the Task key number.
7h of Person A is From Task Z, child of Task G.
7h of Person B is From Task B, child of Task X.

(It means don't calculate time spent for the parent task)

Comment: Is it that `Parent Key` in Column A is the subtask link to `Key` Task link in Column B?!

Comment: Parent Key is the key of "Parent" Task. That task is the subtask of "Parent" task.

Comment: Try the formula in `TASK & SUBTASK` tab. you can cut paste it later into `TASK ONLY`.  If you are directly trying it in `TASK ONLY` tab then you have to define the range like for example `E:E` --> `'TASK & SUBTASK'!E:E`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
=let(
    a,filter({E:E&xlookup(A:A,B:B,C:C,),F:F},D:D="SUBTASK"),
    b,filter({E:E&C:C,F:F},D:D="TASK",not(regexmatch(B:B&"","\b("&textjoin("|",1,A2:A)&")\b"))),
    d,sort(unique(filter({B2:B,C2:C},D2:D="Task")),1,1),
    e,transpose(sort(unique(filter(E2:E,E2:E<>"")),1,1)),
{{"Task key","Parent Task";d},
{e;makearray(counta(index(d,,2)),counta(e),lambda(r,c,ifna(sum(filter(index(a,,2),index(e,,c)&indeX(index(d,,2),r)=index(a,,1))),ifna(sum(filter(index(b,,2),index(e,,c)&indeX(index(d,,2),r)=index(b,,1)))))))}})
```

[image]

**UPDATED FORMULA** (*for drag-down style*)

- Paste this formula in `Cell M2` of `TASK ONLY` tab. you can then drag-it sideways and downside to populate results respectively.

---

```
=let(
    a,filter({'TASK & SUBTASK'!$E:$E&xlookup('TASK & SUBTASK'!$A:$A,'TASK & SUBTASK'!$B:$B,'TASK & SUBTASK'!$C:$C,),'TASK & SUBTASK'!$F:$F},'TASK & SUBTASK'!$D:$D="SUBTASK"),
    b,filter({'TASK & SUBTASK'!$E:$E&'TASK & SUBTASK'!$C:$C,'TASK & SUBTASK'!$F:$F},'TASK & SUBTASK'!$D:$D="TASK",not(regexmatch('TASK & SUBTASK'!$B:$B&"","\b("&textjoin("|",1,'TASK & SUBTASK'!$A$2:$A)&")\b"))),
ifna(sum(filter(index(a,,2),'TASK & SUBTASK'!J$1&'TASK & SUBTASK'!$I2=index(a,,1))),ifna(sum(filter(index(b,,2),'TASK & SUBTASK'!J$1&'TASK & SUBTASK'!$I2=index(b,,1))))))
```

Comment: Hi. It is correct as I checked. However, I need to reorder the tasks (row) in the result list. Is it possible to have another solution?

Comment: sorry I didnt get you. can you maybe elaborate?!

Comment: Currently, with your solution, the "Task Key" column in the result table will be ordered by the function.
Is there any other solution which I can manually order it by dragging like a normal row?

Comment: I've added an updated formula w/instructions in the answer above & works drag-style

Comment: Thank you. I tried on M2 but it showed nothing. I changed the permission of the file so you can edit directly.

Comment: fixed it now. please check it out.

Comment: It works correctly. But I'd like to ask for another help.
I need to list all the subtasks of that person in column C. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi. Could you help?