# List and calculate total value of children items for each parent item

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of Story and Subtask in the second sheet. Subtask is the child of Story (1 Story can contain zero or multiple subtasks). Each Subtask and Story has an unique ID.

My team member will estimate the time spent for their subtasks. The value is in second.
Each member could have multiple subtasks of 1 Story.

Then I have a list of Story (without Subtask) in Sheet 1.

Now I need to fill the subtasks of each member in their column. I aslo need and calculate total hours each member spent for that Story. If the member has more than 1 Subtask within a Story, the time will be the total hours of all Subtaks.

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ptGvYD-JXYVdXyga5e03AAGqd2SE5fIQ6ncAf01Ya1s/edit?usp=sharing

I follow this answer and could achive the result. However, the performance is terrible.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75511425/1685419